# catch sigsegv in other shared libraries (plugin system)

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-libraries, segmentation-fault

I have written a plugin system (based on shared libraries that I load/unload with `dlopen`/`dlclose`), which works quite well.

My problem is that if one of the plugins (libraries) contains an internal bug that is fatal for the whole execution (e.g. lets say some kind of segmentation violation), the whole program crashes.

I'd like to avoid that. I know that there is a possibility to catch signals like `SIGSEGV` (with `signal.h` I think). But I wonder if this is really the right approach in this case.

Also my program is multithreaded. And so I have to know which plugin (or at least which thread) generated the error.

Actually I just want to reload the library in case of an fatal error (or completely unload it after a timeout). What is the 'standard' method of doing this?